# How to put content below navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want the content of my recycler view to go below the navigation bar.
The recyler view goes into the view pager below.
I have tried clipToPadding="false", made the navigationBarTranslucent in the style but nothing seems to works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_drawer_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_main_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:title="@string/app_name"
                    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_main_tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_unselected"
                    >

                </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/fragment_main_view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the recycler view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main_drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/fragment_main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:title="@string/app_name"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_main_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_unselected"
                >

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: That didn't work, it also left my appbar layout unusable

Comment: I changed it, try again

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     tools:openDrawer="start">
     <include
    android:id="@+id/act_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This would work for you